# How to setup EVURLCache in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods

I create a app for loading a website. It loads fine but it takes 2 to 3 min every time. So I choose to implement EVURLCache.
I use the pod for EVURLCache. And I import that in MainVC.
But I don't know how to setup it.
my Aim is to reduce the load time one time it loaded.
GitHub of EVURLCache : https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache

## MainVC

```
import UIKit
import EVURLCache

class MainVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        webView.delegate = self
        
        let BASE_URL = "http://www.xeoscript.com/"
        let url = URL(string: BASE_URL)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        
    }
    
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the appdelegate of the demo, it's enough to add the following line in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
EVURLCache.activate()
```

See the demo appdelegate for the available configuration options.

If you then run the app, then all your content will be downloaded to a Cache folder in your documents folder. The next time you start the app the files will be loaded from there. It's also possible to include that cache folder inside your app so that people will have the data available directly after downloading your app. The only thin you have to do for this is copying the content from the Cache folder to a PreCache folder in the root of your application.

See the demo app to see how it is setup.

Comment: can you solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325780/how-to-load-uiwebview-in-precache-using-evurlcache

Comment: related to EVURLCache

Comment: question answered