# how to load UIWebView in PreCache using EVURLCache

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I am try to create an iOS app, that have a UIWebview and I want to load the website inside it. I try to use EVURLCache for caching. But it doesn't load from the PreCache folder inside my project.

The app run first time fine. But when I try to run again it shows me blank screen only. I think the app try to load the page from the cache, but the app can't find its caches..

I use https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache for caching. And I install via pods

## MainVC

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self

        let url = URL(string: BASE_URL)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }


    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("*****************")
        print(" webViewDidStartLoad(")
        print("*****************")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("*****************")
        print("webViewDidFinishLoad")
        print("*****************")
    }

}
```

## AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        EVURLCache.LOGGING = true // We want to see all caching actions
        EVURLCache.MAX_FILE_SIZE = 26 // We want more than the default: 2^26 = 64MB
        EVURLCache.MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 30 // We want more than the default: 2^30 = 1GB
        EVURLCache.activate()

        return true
    }
```

And I found the Cache folder

```
04/10/2017 18:01:41:952 FedNet)[1696:.] EVURLCache.swift(245) storeCachedResponse(_:for:):
    CACHE save file to Cache  : /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BF935382-BD49-4F37-85A1-C3FA0E1B094B/data/Containers/Data/Application/AF33E59E-1BB4-46CC-9236-BEB42F53D606/Documents/Cache/www.fednetbank.com/corp/l001/consumer/theme/login/img/banner.jpg
```

[image]

And when I run the app with the PreCache folder it gives me a blank screen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a redirect. Redirects are not cached. I tried to solve that with a protocol but I already noticed that it sometimes fails. Could you try removing the following line from EVURLCache and then try again?

```
URLProtocol.registerClass(EVURLProtocol.self)
```

Comment: Blank screen problem is solved.... but how to know the webView is loaded from the PreCache folder inside the project

Comment: If this was the problem, then you had a redirect. since these will not be cached, it wont's do the redirect when offline. This is a problem that I tried to solve with the URLProtocol. I guess it still has some work to do.

Comment: EVURLCache will look in the cache folder and return the data if its there, if its not it will look in the precache folder and if its not there it will fetch the file

Comment: when I run the app in simulator with no internet.... then the app shows a blank screen... I think the app can't fetch the data from PreCache data inside the project. In my app I want to load the initial loading from the PreCache folder when I run the app first time. Is it possible? Then how?

Comment: Make sure the PreCache folder is included in your project. The best way to populate the PreCache folder is by starting with an empty one, then do all the network activity you like and copy the Cache folder content to the PreCache folder.

Comment: how to setup PreCache folder... In above method in the picture is correct or not. I copy the Cache folder into my project. And I rename it as PreCache..

Comment: PRECACHE not found /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BF935382-BD49-4F37-85A1-C3FA0E1B094B/data/Containers/Data/Application/FF8209CD-40FD-40A9-B5F9-10FF0DC0DB6E/Documents/Cache/www.xeoscript.com/index.html

04/13/2017 21:13:11:122 FedNet)[9805:.] EVURLCache.swift(171) cachedResponse(for:):
 The file is probably not put in the local path using NSKeyedArchiver /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BF935382-BD49-4F37-85A1-C3FA0E1B094B/data/Containers/Data/Application/FF8209CD-40FD-40A9-B5F9-10FF0DC0DB6E/Documents/Cache/www.xeoscript.com/index.html

Comment: when I try to install app first time without internet.. It shows like above... I think the PreCache is not detecting.

Comment: the app not load the uiWebView using PreCache stored inside the project?